# Creating calendar entries from events

Tags: calendar, create-records

I have 4 custom objects for managing course schedules and am trying to find out how to write either a flow or query that will propagate the details to calendar rows for enrollees. This is what I have:

- Object A contains the event name and start/end dates for the session it is offered for (example: Jan 1-June 30)
- Object B contains days and times (multiple rows for each day/time)
        * Mondays 8-12
        * Thursdays 9-1
- Object C contains the contact ID's that need to get the entries created on their calendar
- Object D should be a row for each occurrence of the course for the contact from Jan 1-Jan 30.

I'm new to SF so have only done basic workflows and haven't done any APEX code so looking for guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process Builder to create new Event records. Provided the objects that you describe are related, you could start the creation of records the moment you save a new course or training.

[image]